# Can't understand two contradicting sentences in popular book

Tags: meaning-in-context, books, contradiction

The following excerpted paragraph, from the original 1930s public domain version of the popular *[Think & Grow Rich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Think_and_Grow_Rich)* book, reads as a contradiction that I'm having difficulty reconciling in my mind:

> AUTO-SUGGESTION is a term which applies to all suggestions and all
>   self-administered stimuli which reach one's mind through the five
>   senses. Stated in another way, auto-suggestion is self-suggestion. It is the agency of communication between that part of the mind where
>   conscious thought takes place, and that which serves as the seat of
>   action for the subconscious mind.

## Potential Contradiction

The second sentence clearly states that...

> auto-suggestion is self-suggestion

*I.e. A **subset/type** of suggestion just as self-image is a subset/type of image.*

However the first sentence states that auto-suggestion...

> applies to all suggestions [...] which reach one's mind through the
>   five senses.

*I.e. **All** suggestions absolutely rather than mere subset/type of suggestion.*

"Auto-Suggestion" ("Self-Suggestion") clearly implies suggestions made by the self to the self. The first sentence extends the definition to all suggestions which implies suggestions that are not of the self (suggestions from others).

## My Question

How should I read/understand the first and second sentence?:

1. Suggestion from the self/others to the self are "Auto-Suggestion" ("Self-Suggestion").
2. "Auto-Suggestion" ("Self-Suggestion") consists only of suggestions from the self (but not others) to the self.

The specific use of "self" in...

> all **self**-administered stimuli

...implies a distinction. I.e. Why not correspondingly prefix the preceding...

> all suggestions

?

I.e.

> all **self**-suggestions

## What I'm not asking:

A psychology question. Auto-suggestion is a method of psychology. Standard definitions exist in abundance online and I've accordingly cross-examined them. Please note that my question pertains to **what the author was saying and if the author was contradicting himself** and has no bearing on what the academic definition of auto-suggestion is nor does it require any member of this community to be familiar with psychology or any method thereof.

Comment: Well, I guess we can establish that suggestions that reach your mind through a sixth sense do not qualify as auto-suggestion.     :-)    Seriously, I agree with you; the text appears to be self-contradictory.

Comment: If you have a suggestion for yourself, write it down and then read it.  (Do you really expect every line of such a Trumpish book to stand up to detailed analysis?)

Comment: I'm not sure I see a contradiction here.  It appears more like the author lacks the breadth of comprehension to accurately describe a concept of which he has only a tenuous grasp at best.  It would seem that grasp is temporal insomuch as he has been able to leverage it within his own personal growth system, but not effectively communicate it to others.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to realize is that Napoleon Hill's [*T&GR*](http://ebooksoneverything.com/wealth/ThinkandGrowRich.pdf) is nonsense from beginning to end. The book is contradictory, but not quite in the way the OP seems to think. Remember that auto-suggestion is the mechanism whereby the conscious mind delivers thoughts to the subconscious.  The statement in question says that

> AUTO-SUGGESTION is a term which applies to
>
> 1. all suggestions and
> 2. all self-administered stimuli which reach one's mind through the five senses.

The first category is *suggestions*. Nowhere in the book is the term *suggestion* actually defined, but from context it seems to be those conscious thoughts that we call our internal monologue or those thoughts we gather from conversation with others. These suggestions exclude thoughts induced by the *ether*, which is "a great cosmic mass of external forces of vibration", from which "the human mind is constantly attracting vibrations which harmonize with that which DOMINATES [sic] the human mind."<sup>*</sup>

The second category is sensory input that we generate (self-adminster). Thus if you read further, you'll find the exhortation to read chapters of the book aloud, the sound (impinging on the sense of hearing) being "self-administered."

The language leads one to believe that auto-suggestion does not apply to etheric thoughts (as opposed to internal and conversational suggestions) and external stimuli (as oppposed to the self-adminstered kind).

So far, so not contradictory. Unfortunately, three paragraphs after the OP's quote, Hill states that mankind has absolute control over all material passing from the conscious to the subconscous via any sensory stimuli. So the statement is locally consistent but globally contradicted.

---

* Of course this makes no sense. Did you expect anything different?

Comment: You actually read the book that you skewered?

Comment: @aparente001 Parts. As they say, you don't have to eat a whole egg to know it's bad. I'm actually kinda fascinated by the typically-American self-help movement. From *T&GR* to *How to Win Friends and Influence People* (Dale Carnegie)  to *The Power of Positive Thinking* (Norman Vincent Peale) to *The 7 Habits of Highly Effective People* (Stephen Covey) to *The Secret* (Rhonda Byrne). Only the dust jacket designs are different.

Comment: Oh.  I heard a great podcast about someone who wrote self help books.  Do you want me to try to remember what it was?

Comment: @aparente001 That would be a kindness. Thanks.

Comment: If I haven't figured it out in about two days, please remind me.  It was very well done.